# Lockdown MS Project

Tags: ms-project, schedule

Is there a way to lock MS Project into a read-only file that disallows the read-only user from adding or removing columns, changing the size attributes of existing columns or rows, etc.?  The password option has a read only function; however, it still allows the user to add and delete columns, change views, etc.  Specifically, I am looking for a way, if possible, to make the file act like a .pdf file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Creating a World-Readable Project File with a Write-Reservation

What you want is called "write-reservation" in MS-speak. You can find instructions on Microsoft's support site under ["Password-protect a project file"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/password-protect-a-project-file-bdf3c91e-e144-4ee0-8838-548bd9006890). Modify them for your particular use case as follows:

1. Select `File -> Save As`.
2. Don't fill in a `Protection password` if you want to allow anyone to open it read-only.
3. Set the `Write reservation password` to a strong password.
4. Check the `Read-only recommended` box if you're so inclined. *NB: This doesn't actually protect the file; it just adds a warning message when opened read/write.*
5. Distribute the file as you see fit.

### Supported Versions

The instructions above are supported in the following versions of MS Project:

- Project Online Desktop Client
- Project Professional 2013
- Project Professional 2016
- Project Standard 2010
- Project Standard 2013
- Project Standard 2016
- Project Standard 2019
- Project Professional 2019